How would I export figma radial gradient to CAGradientLayer

css with a confidence inspiring comment
background: radial-gradient(423.17% 112.48% at 32.67% 115.21%, #FFD3D3 7.4%, #E7B9B9 24.14%, #596EBB 58.01%, #382A8B 96.1%) /* warning: gradient uses a rotation that is not supported by CSS and may not behave as expected */; 

relevant part of an svg when the screen is exported:
Which yielded this abomination of a code with startpoint and endpoint I have picked off the wall:
static func shouldMakeGradientLayer(frame: CGRect? = nil) -> CAGradientLayer {
        
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        // Define colors
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor(hex: 0xFFD3D3).cgColor,
            UIColor(hex: 0xE7B9B9).cgColor,
            UIColor(hex: 0x596EBB).cgColor,
            UIColor(hex: 0x382A8B).cgColor
        ].reversed()

        // Define locations
        //background: radial-gradient(423.17% 112.48% at 32.67% 115.21%, #FFD3D3 7.4%, #E7B9B9 24.14%, #596EBB 58.01%, #382A8B 96.1%) /* warning: gradient uses a rotation that is not supported by CSS and may not behave as expected */;
//      gradientLayer.locations = [0.0739577, 0.241399, 0.580144, 0.961]
//  make a guess :-[    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.8, 0.9, 1

        // Apply the gradient transform
        gradientLayer.type = .radial
//      let transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-71.2512 * (.pi / 180), 0, 0, 1)
        guard let w = frame?.width, let h = frame?.height else {
            return gradientLayer
        }
//      gradientLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(964.534/w, 1675.8/w, 1), transform)
//      gradientLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 122.5, y: 935.5)

        gradientLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(964.534/w, 1675.8/h, 1)

        let startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        let endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: -2.2, y: 1.4)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint
        gradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint
        if let frame = frame {
            gradientLayer.frame = frame
        }
        return gradientLayer
    }

Question #1: Is there an easier way to get radial gradient ?
or
Question #2: Should I have the UI designer isolate the parts of svg that I need as a background and I bite the bullet adding UIImageView as a background in each and every uiviewcontroller that needs it (30+ screens)?
maybe there is some straighforward way to map CSS percentages to locations array?
UPD: Youtube was prompt to suggest to me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4gUvhG7uFU to get me to hate css a little less. But the disclaimer still stands is that I don;t understand css and could use a hand here.
UPD: what needs to be achieved (ignore the icons and the rest of the cruft)


It would help if you included an image of what you are trying to achieve... Based on the color values you posted, something like this? https://i.sstatic.net/6HcOivhB.png

Good point @DonMag. Added.

OK - do you want to get that exact gradient? Or just close to it? e.g. https://i.sstatic.net/ED26hjaZ.png ... https://i.sstatic.net/xVUwlpEi.png

Just close to it. Yours seems way closer to the one in figma than mine.

Anton -- posted an answer ... hope it helps :)

Linear CAGradientLayer ...

set start point... for example, (0, 0) (top-left)
set end point... for example, (0, 1) (bottom-left)
set n-number of colors, which by default are "spaced" evenly

and we get a top-down gradient.
Radial CAGradientLayer ...

set start point... for example, (0.5, 0.5) (center)

set end point... for example, (0, 0) or (1, 1) or (0, 1) or (1, 0) doesn't matter

set n-number of colors, which by default are "spaced" evenly


and we get a Radial gradient starting from the center.
The general idea -- we start with a radial gradient:

Then position it relative to the view frame:

and it looks similar to this:

For your design, we can set the start point to:
x: 0.0, y: 1.25

that will put the "center point" of the radial at the left-edge, and 125% of the height (25% past the bottom).
Then we can set the end point to:
x: 3.5, y: 0.0

That puts the "outer edge" of the radial at 350% of the width (so, 250% past the right edge), and at the top.
To make things easier on ourselves, we'll create a UIView subclass, with a few "settable" properties:
class RadialGradientView: UIView {

    public var colors: [UIColor] = [] {
        didSet {
            gradLayer.colors = colors.compactMap( { $0.cgColor } )
        }
    }
    public var locationPcts: [Double] = [] {
        didSet {
            gradLayer.locations = locationPcts.compactMap( { NSNumber(floatLiteral: $0 / 100.0) } )
        }
    }
    public var start: CGPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5) {
        didSet {
            gradLayer.startPoint = start
        }
    }
    public var end: CGPoint = .init(x: 1.0, y: 1.0) {
        didSet {
            gradLayer.endPoint = end
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }
    private var gradLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        gradLayer.type = .radial
        
        // defaults, just so we have something to see if colors is not set
        self.start = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.end = .init(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        colors = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow]
        // leave locations at default
    }
    
}

If we create a 300x300 instance of that view and add it as a centered subview - with no other settings:
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor),
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
}

it will look like this:

If we set some custom colors:
        let v = RadialGradientView()

        v.colors = [
            UIColor(hex: 0xFFD3D3),
            UIColor(hex: 0xE7B9B9),
            UIColor(hex: 0x596EBB),
            UIColor(hex: 0x382A8B),
        ]
        

we get this:

and custom start/end points:
        let v = RadialGradientView()

        v.colors = [
            UIColor(hex: 0xFFD3D3),
            UIColor(hex: 0xE7B9B9),
            UIColor(hex: 0x596EBB),
            UIColor(hex: 0x382A8B),
        ]
        
        v.start = .init(x: 0.0, y: 1.25)
        v.end = .init(x: 3.5, y: 0.0)

We're close to what we want:

The next step is to use that as the background of the view controller... of course, probably multiple controllers. And, we don't want to have to add and constrain that as a subview every time.
So, let's subclass UIViewController:
class MyCustomBackgroundViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func loadView() {
        
        let v = RadialGradientView()
        
        v.colors = [
            UIColor(hex: 0xFFD3D3),
            UIColor(hex: 0xE7B9B9),
            UIColor(hex: 0x596EBB),
            UIColor(hex: 0x382A8B),
        ]
        
        // here you can to "tweak" the start, end and locations values
        //  to get your desired appearance
        v.start = .init(x: 0.0, y: 1.25)
        v.end = .init(x: 3.5, y: 0.0)
        //v.locationPcts = [7.4, 24.14, 58.01, 96.1]
        
        self.view = v
    }
    
}

and, use that class instead of UIViewController for all of our controllers:
class AnotherViewController: MyCustomBackgroundViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // everything normally as with any UIViewController
        
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
            imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "photo") {
            imgView.image = img
            imgView.tintColor = .white
        }
        
    }
    
}

and (hopefully) we're on our way:


Can't thank you enough to explain the anatomy of the start and endpoint props. Not sure if you'd be interest to be in charge of whipping the tech writers at Apple Space Quest style... Before you input the code with the color reversal was akin to this https://youtu.be/jbmq9P-8FiM?t=33

Enum to specify the direction of the radial gradient
enum RadialGradientDirection {
    case centerToEdge
    case edgeToCenter
}

Extension to UIView to add radial gradient functionality
extension UIView {
    func applyRadialGradient(colors: [UIColor], direction: RadialGradientDirection, radius: CGFloat? = nil) {
        let gradientLayer = RadialGradientLayer()
        
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
        
        // Define the center and the radius for the gradient
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let endRadius = radius ?? max(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        
        switch direction {
        case .centerToEdge:
            gradientLayer.startCenter = center
            gradientLayer.endCenter = center
            gradientLayer.startRadius = 0
            gradientLayer.endRadius = endRadius
            
        case .edgeToCenter:
            gradientLayer.startCenter = center
            gradientLayer.endCenter = center
            gradientLayer.startRadius = endRadius
            gradientLayer.endRadius = 0
        }
        
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
    
    func removeRadialGradient() {
        layer.sublayers?
            .filter { $0 is RadialGradientLayer } // Find all radial gradient layers
            .forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() } // Remove them
    }
}

Custom radial gradient layer
class RadialGradientLayer: CALayer {
    var colors: [CGColor] = []
    var startCenter: CGPoint = .zero
    var endCenter: CGPoint = .zero
    var startRadius: CGFloat = 0
    var endRadius: CGFloat = 0
    
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        ctx.saveGState()
        
        // Create a gradient with the provided colors
        guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: colors as CFArray, locations: nil) else { return }
        
        // Draw the radial gradient
        ctx.drawRadialGradient(
            gradient,
            startCenter: startCenter,
            startRadius: startRadius,
            endCenter: endCenter,
            endRadius: endRadius,
            options: .drawsBeforeStartLocation
        )
        
        ctx.restoreGState()
    }
}


thanks, gotta check it out. Any advantages drawing to CGContext instead of using higher level API of CAGradientLayer ?

For simple, static gradients, CAGradientLayer is often sufficient and efficient. For complex, dynamic graphics, CGContext might offer better performance and flexibility.
